# RAND() not consistently generating the right length value

Tags: sql, random

I've got the following code in place with the idea being that I need a 30 character random number generated each time the stored procedure is called and the odd thing is that in most cases it works as intended but in other seemingly random cases it will only generate a 28 character random number.

```
'\\xxx-servername\folder\'+
    CAST(CAST((RAND()*1000000000000000000000000000000) as decimal(30))as varchar(30)) +
    RAM.AccountNumber+HRMRN.PrefixMedicalRecordNumber+'ESTIMATE       N00001'+
        REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),ISNULL(HRM.Birthdate,HRM.BirthdateComputed),111),'/','')+HRM.Sex+
            REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),GetDate(),111),'/','')+LEFT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),GetDate(),108),':',''),4)+'.PDF' as [CPFileName]
```

Hope maybe someone can offer some advice because I'm at a loss...

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your system is automatically removing leading zeros.  You can either re-insert those zeros yourself, or else construct your number using something like:

```
number <- ""
number.append(randomDigit(1,9))
repeat 29 times
  number.append(randomDigit(0,9))
end repeat
```

That guarantees that you do not get a leading zero.